# CMake to link against non numbered libraries

Tags: cmake

How can I instruct CMake to link against the non-numbered version of a library? For instance when using the Boost libraries I have:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS regex program_options REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY})
```

and the executable links against libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0 . If I try to run this executable in an older machine it will fail because that library can't be found although I know that this functionality is already present in that library version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't work.  Even though the functionality is there, the exact API may not be there.  That's why the UNIX linking system uses symlinks, so that the linker accesses the unnumbered symlink, then dereferences it when writing out the list of dependencies, to require the same major version at runtime.

You have 3 choices:

1. Recompile on your target machine with the older boost.
2. Distribute the necessary boost library along with your executable.  This probably involves writing a launch script that sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running.
3. Link against the static boost libraries to eliminate your runtime dependency.  Use this line before find_package:

`SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)`